# Cannot Save Images from URL in Nativescript/Javascript with imageSource module

Tags: javascript, android, image, nativescript

## Context

I'm trying to download a users' Facebook profile picture to the local storage so that I can display it without having to remake the call to Facebook.

## Code

I'm using the module `image-source` to download the image, and the module `file-system` to access the device's local storage.

Most of the code is referencing [the Nativescript `image-source` documentation page](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/image-source#save-image-source-to-png-or-jpg-file).

```
var imageSource = require("image-source");
var fs = require("file-system");

exports.theFunction = function(args){
    //...
        var img = imageSource.fromFile("http://graph.facebook.com/"+user.id+"/picture?type=large");
        var folder = fs.knownFolders.documents();
        var path = fs.path.join(folder.path, "profilePic.jpg");
        console.log(path);

        var saved = img.saveToFile(path, enums.ImageFormat.jpg);
        appSettings.setString("imgLocal",path);

        console.log("Image Saved Successfully");
    //...
}
```

## Output

> /data/user/0/com.foo.bar/files/profilePic.jpg

I never see the "Image Saved Successfully" message output to console and I have no way of verifying if the image has been stored in the filesystem using the Emulator (I'm developing for Android without a device).

I have also tried wrapping the save event in an `if` tag, assuming that the output of `saveToFile()` is a boolean:

```
if(img.saveToFile(path, enums.ImageFormat.jpg)) console.log("success");
    else console.log("failure");
```

...however this also outputs nothing.

## Question

How can I save the image from the URL to the device's local storage?

*References*

- [Nativescript](http://www.nativescript.org)
- [image-source on Nativescript docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/image-source#save-image-source-to-png-or-jpg-file)
- [ImageSource on Nativescript API docs](http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_source_.imagesource.html)

Comment: Hi Ben, were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I think main trouble here is in that line, cause ImageSource works only with local files, not urls:

```
var img = imageSource.fromFile("http://graph.facebook.com/"+user.id+"/picture?type=large");
```

You should download image, not set source from url. About downloading image you can read here:
https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/image-cache

Or try something like this and save it than somehow:

```
var image = new ImageModule.Image();
image.src = "https://www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2.png";
```

But about this I'm not quite sure. I've never used nativescript and just looked through the docs.